# If $A_n$ is a countable collection of sets in $F$ with $\mu(A_n) = 1 $ for $ n\geq 1$ then: $\mu\big(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \big) = 1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I just started learning Measure Theory in a Probability Course.
I am having trouble understanding the significance and the proof of the following theorem.

Let $(\Omega, F, \mu)$ be a measure space.

If $\mu$ is a probability measure and $A_n$ is a countable collection of events in $F$ with $\mu(A_n) = 1 $ for $ n\geq 1$ then:

$$\mu\big(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \big) = 1$$

Comment: You have to be missing something. Pick $\mu$ as the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $A_n := (n,n+1)$. That is clearly a counterexample.

Comment: The sequence os sets $A_n$ is monotone ($A_n \subset A_{n+1}$ or $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$)?

Comment: @FranCruz $\mu$ is a probability measure

Comment: Oh, sorry. Work with $\Omega \setminus A_n$, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** The simple way to solve this is to show that

$$ \mu \Bigg( \Big( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\Big)^c \Bigg)=0 .$$

Try using De-Morgan's law, and recall that $\mu\big( A_n^c \big)=0 $ for all $n$.

The significance of this statement, is that with respect to $\mu$, you only care what happens with probability $1$. Everything else is indistinguishable with respect to $\mu$.

Comment: To add to this: it is *very* necessary that $\mu(\Omega) = 1$. A quick counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Lebesgue measure would be taking $A_n = (n, n+1)$. You could do this for a finite measure in general (adjusted accordingly), but once you are working with infinite measures, things get fuzzy.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think his space is denoted by $\Omega$ rahter than $F$.

Comment: Oh lol yep. I should have scrolled up. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: in this case, it is specified that $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$, so the condition is satisfied

Comment: @NHL right, just adding on for OP's intuition since measure theory is a delicate topic.

Comment: Also adding on to my prior comment: countable is also important here (not just because measures work best with countable operations) since you could take $A_x = \Omega\setminus\{x\}$ for $x\in \Omega$. Provided that singletons have measure $0$, each of these will have measure $1$, but then $\cap_{x\in\Omega} A_x = \emptyset$ which has measure $0$.